# PasswordRecovery control problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

ASP.NET PasswordRecovery control usually asks 2 questions for recovering users password. First the username and then the secret question. Is there any way where we can make it to ask only one question - username only?

Comment: *`Password recovery in VS 2008`*??? Could you clarify?

Comment: I think he/she is talking about http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/PasswordRecovery10032008150514PM/PasswordRecovery.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the built in `PasswordRecovery` control and `Membership`

In the web.config file, you can specify if the security question is required. Set this to false, then all the user should have to do is enter their username.

See here http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/recovering-and-changing-passwords-vb

Comment: Thnx Tim for ur help.. The article says set requiresQuestionAndAnswer to false if u dont want security question and that will be in membership provider configuration. I dont find membership provider in web.config file

Comment: Well what are you using for your Authentication? Custom one?

Comment: In select authentication, i chose from the internet